# Use arithmetic of counters inside \cline

Tags: tables, counters, columns, arithmetic, cline

I have a custom counter `\myCounter` set to, say 3.
I need to produce such a table:

[image]

The following code does not work:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcounter{myCounter}
\setcounter{myCounter}{3}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{cl*{\value{myCounter}{c}c}}
& \multicolumn{\value{myCounter}}{c}
    {agglutinate} & \\\cline{2-\value{myCounter+1}} % Here is the naive part
init & content1 & content2 & content3 & end \\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

How should I perform counter arithmetics within `\cline`?

Comment: Why do you show only a snippet instead of a full example people could compile directly?

Comment: Usually I would say `\numexpr` but with a fixed number of `&` this is not really useful, is it?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I do it in order to keep the question clear. Also because the snippet I show does not compile anyway. BTW I wished there was a way to compile LaTeX code inside the stack interface, just like you can get formulae within `$$` in Maths SE. This way I would not have to insert a screenshot of my table. Is this possible?

Comment: It doesn't make the question clearer, it is simply a nuisance that I have to type \newcounter, \setcounter, \documentclass etc to try out a solution. And if you had to try out your example first you perhaps would have realized that there are brace errors beside the \cline-problem.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer You're right. `came from a good intention though.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Is there a way to compile LaTeX code directly from this site, so that we wouldn't need to upload screenshots of our products?

Comment: No. But while screenshots are neat, there are not really necessary if your question contains a sensible complete example. I can always compile on my system. And you can simply write "I want a line about content1 to content3."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Calculations can be done with `\numexpr number1 operator number2`, but in this case, the example is a little bit useless, since the number of `&` is fixed to use 3 columns (in between) anyway!

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcounter{myCounter}

\setcounter{myCounter}{3}
\begin{document}



\begin{tabular}{cl*{\value{myCounter}}{c}c}
  & \multicolumn{\value{myCounter}}{c}{agglutinate} & \tabularnewline
    \cline{2-{\numexpr\value{myCounter}+1}}
init & content1 & content2 & content3 & end \\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is what I was looking for! Consider this as "half-useful". When I add a section to my document, I have to manually add a  `&` and a `contentN` into the `tabular` environment, but the rest of the table automatically scales up ;) Cheers!

Comment: @Iago-lito: If `contentX` would be computable the whole approach would be much more usable ;-)

Comment: Yupe. Unfortunately it is not. Even though I would *love* my computer to write this article for me while I'm having a chocolate. Hey, machines can't do everything, can they? ;)

Comment: @Iago-lito: Not yet :D